# Download images from pages doesn't work in some pages using BeautifulSoap

Tags: python, image-processing, beautifulsoup

Am trying to write python script to Get list of images from pages it worked for all pages expect this page [The URL](https://www.olx.com.eg/en/ad/iphone-11-pro-max-256-99-IDbVsfw.html)no idea why

```
from bs4 import *
import requests
import os

def main(url):
    
    # content of URL
    r = requests.get(url)

    # Parse HTML Code
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    # find all images in URL
    images = soup.findAll('img')

# take url
url = "https://www.olx.com.eg/ad/-IDbWEaD.html"

# CALL MAIN FUNCTION
main(url)
```

when i tried to trace the code i found it the request always gives

> <Response [503]>

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow` community! for your next questions, Kindly please shorten your question and limit it to specific target in order to make it easier for both of us to be able to help you. you might love to check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη ty i will do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to include the `User-Agent` according to [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4)

Please note the following point:

1. Don't try/except if you already have a logic to match to increase the speed of your process. since you aware that all links ends with `.jpg`.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    print([x['src'] for x in soup.find_all('img', src=re.compile(".jpg$"))])


main('https://www.olx.com.eg/en/ad/iphone-11-pro-max-256-99-IDbVsfw.html')
```

Output:

```
['https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/d8ny85zq521f3-EG/image;s=861x156;olx-st/_2_.jpg', 'https://olxegstatic-a.akamaihd.net/c753187-12042/naspersclassifieds-regional/olxmena-atlas-web/static/img/takovr/en/700x500.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/fdx5st507obs-EG/image;s=644x461;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/9a8up5kipf3w3-EG/image;s=644x461;olx-st/_2_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/33gbpla9epxt3-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/36phurpqbyd52-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_3_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/t93mj7wc7tf2-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/wyp080mr7p3d3-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_2_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/oaqb85wgs8qf1-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/fdx5st507obs-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/9a8up5kipf3w3-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_2_.jpg']
```

If I'm blind and don't know the exact tags:

So let's use `regex` as below [check online](https://regex101.com/r/QliLXR/1/):

```
match = re.findall(r'\"(http.*?jpg)\"', r.text)
print(match)
```

Output:

```
['https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/fdx5st507obs-EG/image;s=644x461;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/fdx5st507obs-EG/image;s=644x461;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/d8ny85zq521f3-EG/image;s=861x156;olx-st/_2_.jpg', 'https://olxegstatic-a.akamaihd.net/c753187-12042/naspersclassifieds-regional/olxmena-atlas-web/static/img/takovr/en/700x500.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/fdx5st507obs-EG/image;s=644x461;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/9a8up5kipf3w3-EG/image;s=644x461;olx-st/_2_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/33gbpla9epxt3-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/36phurpqbyd52-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_3_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/t93mj7wc7tf2-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/wyp080mr7p3d3-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_2_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/oaqb85wgs8qf1-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/fdx5st507obs-EG/image;s=1000x700;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/fdx5st507obs-EG/image;s=94x72;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/9a8up5kipf3w3-EG/image;s=1000x700;olx-st/_2_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/9a8up5kipf3w3-EG/image;s=94x72;olx-st/_2_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/fdx5st507obs-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_1_.jpg', 'https://apollo-ireland.akamaized.net/v1/files/9a8up5kipf3w3-EG/image;s=261x203;olx-st/_2_.jpg']
```

Comment: ty very much its perfect answer

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη if i want to get all the urls from the pagination then apply this code . i do same method or its another story 1

Comment: @memi i didn't get your question. also be aware that we are limited to provide an answer according to the initial question asked <

Comment: @QHarr :) Based on experience. that's a quick note.

Comment: okie i figured out my self . i just was trying to make script to for loop of each page from pagination then get all content from them . but i solved it ty for the help !